# My default desktop environment changed

Tags: tty

Basically my default desktop environment (Console? Maybe not desktop environment- I'm not sure what this is) changed from tty2 to tty5 suddenly. I would like to get to my desktop when I press C+M+2 instead of C+M+5. I would be grateful for your help.

I'm working with 18.04, Bionic Beaver.

Comment: your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Console assignment has changed since I believe Ubuntu 17.10. tty1 is the login screen, tty2 the graphical desktop (used to be tty7), so tty3 and higher provide free consoles.